# Error SqlLite Query with Android 5.0 API 21

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

[image]

**This error occurs with android 5.0 APi 21 but this code works perfectly with Android API 33**

I'm using SimpleSQLiteQuery to create my select query[![enter image description here

```
override fun getPropertyBySearch(
    type: String,
    city: String,
    minSurface: Int,
    maxSurface: Int,
    minPrice: Int,
    maxPrice: Int,
    onTheMarketLessALastWeek: Boolean,
    soldOn3LastMonth: Boolean,
    min3photos: Boolean,
    schools: Boolean,
    shops: Boolean
): LiveData<List<RealEstateDatabase>> {

    val iso = ISOChronology.getInstance()
    val today = LocalDate(iso)

    Log.e("today",today.toString())

    val dateMinusThreeMonth = today.minusMonths(3)
    val dateMinus1Week = today.minusDays(7)

    Log.e("dateMinusThreeMonth",dateMinusThreeMonth.toString())
    Log.e("dateMinus1Week",dateMinus1Week.toString())

    val query = """SELECT * FROM RealEstateDatabase WHERE 
                    ('$type' ='' OR type LIKE '%$type%' ) AND 
                    ('$city' ='' OR city LIKE '%$city%' ) AND
                    ($schools = false OR schoolsNear = $schools ) AND 
                    ($shops = false OR shopsNear = $shops ) AND 
                    ($min3photos = false OR count_photo >= 3 ) AND
                    ($minSurface =0 AND $maxSurface = 0  OR  area BETWEEN $minSurface AND $maxSurface  ) AND 
                    ($minPrice =0 AND $maxPrice = 0  OR  price BETWEEN $minPrice AND $maxPrice ) AND 
                    ($onTheMarketLessALastWeek = false  OR  dateOfEntry BETWEEN '$dateMinus1Week' AND '$today' ) AND 
                    ($soldOn3LastMonth = false  OR dateOfSale BETWEEN '$dateMinusThreeMonth' AND '$today') """

    Log.e("query", query)


    return realEstateDao.getPropertyBySearch(SimpleSQLiteQuery(query))
}
```

Here is the table in question

```
@Entity
@Parcelize
data class RealEstateDatabase(
@PrimaryKey
var id: String,
var type: String? = null,
var price: Int? = null,
var area: Int? = null,
var numberRoom: String? = null,
var description: String? = null,
var numberAndStreet: String? = null,
var numberApartment: String? = null,
var city: String? = null,
var region: String? = null,
var postalCode: String? = null,
var country: String? = null,
var status: String? = null,
var dateOfEntry: String? = null,
var dateOfSale: String? = null,
var realEstateAgent: String? = null,
var lat: Double ?=null,
var lng: Double ?=null,
var hospitalsNear : Boolean = false,
var schoolsNear : Boolean = false,
var shopsNear : Boolean = false,
var parksNear : Boolean = false,
@ColumnInfo(name = "listPhotoWithText")
var listPhotoWithText : List<PhotoWithTextFirebase> ?=null,
var count_photo : Int? = listPhotoWithText?.size,
)
```

I don't explain that this code works on one api rather than another, I'm leaning towards a non-compatibility of my sql lite query but I'm not sure or how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant **false** (as well as **true**) was introduced in version 3.23.0 of SQLite; as per :-

- > 2018-04-02 (3.23.0)

  - > 1. Add the sqlite3_serialize() and sqlite3_deserialize() interfaces when the SQLITE_ENABLE_DESERIALIZE compile-time option is used.
  - > 2. **Recognize TRUE and FALSE as constants.** (For compatibility, if there exist columns named "true" or "false", then the identifiers refer to the columns rather than Boolean constants.)
  - > Support operators IS TRUE, IS FALSE, IS NOT TRUE, and IS NOT FALSE.
  - https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

As such only android API's of 30+ support the use of true and false, as per

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Instead you could use 0 instead of false (non zero, typically 1 for true). e.g.

```
val query = """SELECT * FROM RealEstateDatabase WHERE 
                    ('$type' ='' OR type LIKE '%$type%' ) AND 
                    ('$city' ='' OR city LIKE '%$city%' ) AND
                    ($schools = 0 OR schoolsNear = $schools ) AND 
                    ($shops = 0 OR shopsNear = $shops ) AND 
                    ($min3photos = 0 OR count_photo >= 3 ) AND
                    ($minSurface =0 AND $maxSurface = 0  OR  area BETWEEN $minSurface AND $maxSurface  ) AND 
                    ($minPrice =0 AND $maxPrice = 0  OR  price BETWEEN $minPrice AND $maxPrice ) AND 
                    ($onTheMarketLessALastWeek = 0  OR  dateOfEntry BETWEEN '$dateMinus1Week' AND '$today' ) AND 
                    ($soldOn3LastMonth = 0  OR dateOfSale BETWEEN '$dateMinusThreeMonth' AND '$today') """
```